# How to change the font size of my Latex document

Tags: latex, overleaf

I found this latex template that has no font-size attribute, but the writing is just too small to be read.
Hope you can help me figuring out how to change the font size, the template has a file called arxiv.sty that contains:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProcessOptions\relax

% fonts
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

% set page geometry
\usepackage[verbose=true,letterpaper]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \newgeometry{
    textheight=9in,
    textwidth=6.5in,
    top=1in,
    headheight=14pt,
    headsep=25pt,
    footskip=30pt
  }
}

\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\flushbottom
\sloppy

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyheadoffset{0pt}
\rhead{\scshape \today}
\cfoot{\thepage}


%Handling Keywords
\def\keywordname{{\bfseries \emph Keywords}}%
\def\keywords#1{\par\addvspace\medskipamount{\rightskip=0pt plus1cm
\def\and{\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\fi\ $\cdot$
}\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1\par}}

% font sizes with reduced leading
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
  \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xipt
  \abovedisplayskip      7\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 5\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus 3\p@
  \belowdisplayskip      \abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 3\p@
}
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\small}{%
  \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt\@xpt
  \abovedisplayskip      6\p@ \@plus 1.5\p@ \@minus 4\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@  \@plus 2\p@
  \belowdisplayskip      \abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus 2\p@   \@minus 2\p@
}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt\@xpt}
\renewcommand{\scriptsize}{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt}
\renewcommand{\tiny}{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt\@viipt}
\renewcommand{\large}{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{16}}
\renewcommand{\LARGE}{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{20}}
\renewcommand{\huge}{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{23}}
\renewcommand{\Huge}{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{28}}

% sections with less space
\providecommand{\section}{}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                {-2.0ex \@plus -0.5ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
                { 1.5ex \@plus  0.3ex \@minus  0.2ex}%
                {\large\bf\raggedright}%
}
\providecommand{\subsection}{}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                {-1.8ex \@plus -0.5ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
                { 0.8ex \@plus  0.2ex}%
                {\normalsize\bf\raggedright}%
}
\providecommand{\subsubsection}{}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                {-1.5ex \@plus -0.5ex \@minus -0.2ex}%
                { 0.5ex \@plus  0.2ex}%
                {\normalsize\bf\raggedright}%
}
\providecommand{\paragraph}{}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                {1.5ex \@plus 0.5ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
                {-1em}%
                {\normalsize\bf}%
}
\providecommand{\subparagraph}{}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{%
  \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                {1.5ex \@plus 0.5ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
                {-1em}%
                {\normalsize\bf}%
}
\providecommand{\subsubsubsection}{}
\renewcommand{\subsubsubsection}{%
  \vskip5pt{\noindent\normalsize\rm\raggedright}%
}

% float placement
\renewcommand{\topfraction      }{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction   }{0.4}
\renewcommand{\textfraction     }{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}

\newlength{\@abovecaptionskip}\setlength{\@abovecaptionskip}{7\p@}
\newlength{\@belowcaptionskip}\setlength{\@belowcaptionskip}{\z@}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\@abovecaptionskip}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\@belowcaptionskip}

% swap above/belowcaptionskip lengths for tables
\renewenvironment{table}
  {\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\@belowcaptionskip}%
   \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\@abovecaptionskip}%
   \@float{table}}
  {\end@float}

% footnote formatting
\setlength{\footnotesep }{6.65\p@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{9\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern-3\p@ \hrule width 12pc \kern 2.6\p@}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

% paragraph formatting
\setlength{\parindent}{\z@}
\setlength{\parskip  }{5.5\p@}

% list formatting
\setlength{\topsep       }{4\p@ \@plus 1\p@   \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength{\partopsep    }{1\p@ \@plus 0.5\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@}
\setlength{\itemsep      }{2\p@ \@plus 1\p@   \@minus 0.5\p@}
\setlength{\parsep       }{2\p@ \@plus 1\p@   \@minus 0.5\p@}
\setlength{\leftmargin   }{3pc}
\setlength{\leftmargini  }{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\leftmarginii }{2em}
\setlength{\leftmarginiii}{1.5em}
\setlength{\leftmarginiv }{1.0em}
\setlength{\leftmarginv  }{0.5em}
\def\@listi  {\leftmargin\leftmargini}
\def\@listii {\leftmargin\leftmarginii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \topsep  2\p@ \@plus 1\p@    \@minus 0.5\p@
              \parsep  1\p@ \@plus 0.5\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@
              \itemsep \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \topsep    1\p@ \@plus 0.5\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@
              \parsep    \z@
              \partopsep 0.5\p@ \@plus 0\p@ \@minus 0.5\p@
              \itemsep \topsep}
\def\@listiv {\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv  {\leftmargin\leftmarginv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi {\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
              \labelwidth\leftmarginvi
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}

% create title
\providecommand{\maketitle}{}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
    % for perfect author name centering
    \renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox to \z@{$^{\@thefnmark}$\hss}}
    % The footnote-mark was overlapping the footnote-text,
    % added the following to fix this problem               (MK)
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{%
      \parindent 1em\noindent
      \hbox to 1.8em{\hss $\m@th ^{\@thefnmark}$}##1
    }
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \@maketitle
    \@thanks
    %\@notice
  \endgroup
  \let\maketitle\relax
  \let\thanks\relax
}

% rules for title box at top of first page
\newcommand{\@toptitlebar}{
  \hrule height 2\p@
  \vskip 0.25in
  \vskip -\parskip%
}
\newcommand{\@bottomtitlebar}{
  \vskip 0.29in
  \vskip -\parskip
  \hrule height 2\p@
  \vskip 0.09in%
}

% create title (includes both anonymized and non-anonymized versions)
\providecommand{\@maketitle}{}
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \vbox{%
    \hsize\textwidth
    \linewidth\hsize
    \vskip 0.1in
    \@toptitlebar
    \centering
    {\LARGE\sc \@title\par}
    \@bottomtitlebar
    \textsc{}\\
    \vskip 0.1in
    \def\And{%
      \end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[0]\hfil%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}\ignorespaces%
    }
    \def\AND{%
      \end{tabular}\hfil\linebreak[4]\hfil%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}\ignorespaces%
    }
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\rule{\z@}{24\p@}\@author\end{tabular}%
  \vskip 0.4in \@minus 0.1in \center{\today}   \vskip 0.2in
  }
}

% add conference notice to bottom of first page
\newcommand{\ftype@noticebox}{8}
\newcommand{\@notice}{%
  % give a bit of extra room back to authors on first page
  \enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}%
  \@float{noticebox}[b]%
    \footnotesize\@noticestring%
  \end@float%
}

% abstract styling
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{
  \centerline
  {\large \bfseries \scshape Abstract}
  \begin{quote}
}
{
  \end{quote}
}

\endinput
```

and the template.tex file that contains the code below but no attributes telling about the font-size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{arxiv}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{
```

Comment: Easiest way is to change via the documentclass, but as you don't show a [mre] and no documentclass ....

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added the link to the template if that helps

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question and not in a link

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the font settings of the .sty file by loading `size11.clo` or `size12.clo` afterwards.

These files will create nice matching sets of font sizes, so that it not only changes the size of the formal text but also adjust other sizes like `\large` etc. to get an harmonic result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{arxiv}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{test}

\makeatletter
%\input{size11.clo}
\input{size12.clo}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```